# How to use AJAX with multiple nested forms? "The Gym Plan" problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-forms

I want to be able to fill a table with some data through AJAX. My problem is that this data is from two different models. This will be long but please bear with me.

Imagine an application that would fill the plan for working out at the gym (clearly not an application for me :D). This plan has many routines (per type basis or day basis) which has many steps to go through.

Is it possible to use AJAX to fill a nice table that fills dynamically? Ideally I would prefer to save and display a table each time the user fills any new data.

What I have so far:

In the models I added the accepts_nested_attributes_for property.

I am using [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) that allows us to add and remove nested models.

Let's take a look at our form:

- app/views/plans/_form.html.erb

  ```
  <%= nested_form_for @plan, :url => plan_path(@plan), :html => { :class => :form } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Plan Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.fields_for :routines do |r| %>
      <%= render 'routine_fields', :f => r %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add a routine", :routines %>
  <% end %>
  ```

So fields_for allows us to save many routines inside a plan, NICE! Let's define our fields views:

- app/views/plans/_routine_fields.html.erb

  ```
  <%= f.label :name, "Routine Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :steps do |s| %>
    <%= render 'step_fields', :f => s %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add a step", :steps %>
  <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this routine" %>
  ```
- app/views/plans/_step_fields.html.erb

  ```
  <%= f.label :name, "Step Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this step" %>
  ```

This works great! We can add as many routines inside a plan and many steps inside a routine we are able to create a complete plan in one view.

BUT IS UGLY! and also very confusing! So my problem again: How would I update the table each time the user fills any new data?

Ideal:

[image: Ideal Example]

Comment: Can you edit you question to be concise, I started reading it, but got lost in the scaffolding :P

Comment: I added a paragraph a the beginning (before the scaffold) that explains what I want the question is probably better if you read the whole thing

Comment: I didn't and that's what I wanted to convey. If you want your question to be answered, be concise. Nobody wants to read a tutorial on SO to answer a question.

Comment: This is not a simple problem and some people might find it interesting, that's why I did "the tutorial", if a person likes the challenge just follows the instructions... Anyway if anyone has had this problem before in the last paragraph you can find the question again

Comment: I finally read it. But its still not clear what do you want? Do you want to update the table as the user fills in the information in the form or do you want to submit the form over ajax and display what the plan is in a table format?

Comment: Any of those solutions would be great, but I prefer to save and display a table each time the user fills any new data

Comment: Can you post the table format the final plan looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that you could use for this would be to break up the form into different forms that are loaded via ajax, and just continuously update attributes on a model.  You could also just use the form that you have now and break up the html so that it doesn't all show in a table.

For dealing with forms, you could check out the [railscast on wicked](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked)

For dealing with ajax, there is a very good [railscast on ajax/jquery](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised)

You could also break up this logic into different partials, and change the UX a bit, so that a user still has the same functionality, but it lives on a different view.  You can add ajax to this by following the previously mentioned ajax railscast or using the [turbolinks gem](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) (though turbolinks is a bit different).

It seems to me that this is primarily a UX problem, and you're trying to crowbar a particular implementation into a rigid UX.  I would try reframing the UX to see if there is a more elegant solution to the problems you have mentioned.

Comment: The answer was that! We changed the UX a lot in the end because it was too rigid.